# Dialog: how make dialog content scroll-able?

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

Anyway to have Dialog's content scroll-able?
We have sometimes Dialog content with a lot of content and we just would like to have it scrollable. Here sample with Boostrap and only modal content scrollable: http://www.bootply.com/WaTI0dBpa3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time the dialog does not have a property that enables scrolling. You can achieve this by adding a scrollable `div` element inside the dialog and adding a few styles:

```
<kendo-dialog title="Dialog">
    <div style="height:200px; overflow:auto; padding:1.143em; margin:-1.143em;">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>

    <kendo-dialog-actions style="margin: 0">
        <button kendoButton>OK</button>
    </kendo-dialog-actions>
</kendo-dialog>
```

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0qiXOper6pDWwTcQMz17?p=preview) for a runnable demo.

This is a good feature and has been logged for implementation for an upcoming version of the dialog.

Answer (score 3):

setting the [height] attribute will automatically add the scroll bar to the dialog.

```html
<kendo-dialog title="Update" (close)="closeEditProfileDetails()" [height]= 800>
content here....
</kendo-dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

In current `v5.0` of Kendo React (so probably the same in Angular) you can make sure all the dialogs/windows don't extend off screen using CSS:

```css
.k-window {
  max-height: 90vh;
}
```

In this case I set the max height for a window to 90% of the screen height so that there is still a little bit of the translucent backdrop showing to indicate that you are in a modal dialog still.